# Why does brew have a python package (unversioned) and a version-specific python package?

Tags: homebrew

I'm new to brew. Why does brew have both a python and a python@3.8 package? If I do a "brew search", many of the packages don't have version numbers in them.

It's also interesting how if I do a "brew search openssl", it only shows me openss@1.1, but not just openssl.

Comment: The unversioned one is what the undiscerning user normally wants. The versioned one is for folks who have specific (non-standard) needs. Unversioned `python` currently gets you v3.7 and the versioned `python@3.8` is not quite ready for prime time AFAIK. I'm happy to be corrected if wrong, please say if anyone knows better.

Comment: Thanks. I installed the awscli package the other day, and it installed python@3.8 as a dependency. Maybe that's another reason why someone (or another brew package) could want to stick with a particular version, to ensure that things work?

Answer (score 1):

What Mark said is right, we have big chunk of homebrew formulae depends on Python. So using versioned formula would be easier for us to prioritize the python 3.8 migration (we do even have [a migration label](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/labels/python-3.8-migration) for it.)

As you know this is the first year for fully deprecate Python 2, which would be painful for any package manager to do the inventory check. :)